# Heigh Change Tween Animation Issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to animate the Height of My container

What I am try to do is :

```
class _AddVehicleState extends State<AddVehicle>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

   AnimationController _otherFieldsAnimationController;
   Animation<double> _heightAnimation;

  override
  void initState() {
    _otherFieldsAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
    );


    _heightAnimation = new Tween<double>(begin: 400.0, end: 20.0)
        .animate(_otherFieldsAnimationController);

    _otherFieldsAnimationController.forward();

}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: new Scaffold(body: Builder(builder: (scaffoldContext1) {
          scaffoldContext = scaffoldContext1;
          return Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                decoration: getGradientBackground(),
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                       color: Colors.white70,
                       height: _heightAnimation.value,
                       child: Center(
                       child: Text('HEY'),
                    ));
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

As you can see the container contains the height of Animation.

All the other animation on this page works perfectly but this container is not being animated.

Any particular reason? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the animated container like this

```
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController _controller;
      Animation<double> _animation;
      var _duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 3000);

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: _duration,
        )..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
        _animation =
            new Tween<double>(begin: 20.0, end: 400.0).animate(_controller);
_controller.forward();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Stackoverflow'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: _duration,
                height: _animation.value,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Still on luck. Not animating at all

Comment: This is a tested code, try to run this alone, then figure out how to fit onto yours

Comment: even I know my code is correct but the thing what is stopping the animation I want to know that

Comment: Then post the complete code, and how do you know your code is correct, if it is not working at all

Comment: I already posted the required thing. it has nothing apart from what I have posted

Comment: ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });  i think you forget this

Comment: OK let me try. Give me 10 minute

Comment: ..addListener(() { setState(() {}); }) can you explain me what this line do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191016/discussion-between-lakhwinder-singh-and-abubakker-moallim).